# How to tune not in query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, query-optimization

Please tune my query.It took 17 sec for execution

```
  SELECT grirno, grirdate
    FROM grirmain
   WHERE     grirno NOT IN
                 (SELECT grirno
                    FROM grir_pass
                   WHERE ins_check IS NOT NULL AND grirdate > '01-apr-2013')
         AND grirno IS NOT NULL
         AND chkuser IS NOT NULL
         AND grirdate > '01-apr-2013'
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (GRIRNO,INSTR (GRIRNO,'/',1,1)+ 1,(  INSTR (GRIRNO,'/',1,2)- INSTR (GRIRNO,'/',1,1)- 1))) DESC
```

Comment: can you provide us an execution plan or something?

Comment: You're querying six years worth of data. So, how fast do you think this query should be? How many rows in GRIRMAIN and GRIR_PASS? How many rows from each table after you've applied the filtering criteria? How many rows in GRIRMAIN filtered results which aren't in GRIR_PASS results? Are the tables partitioned? There are a lot of factors which affect Oracle performance: please read [this post of Oracle tuning questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325) then **edit your question** to provide more of the details we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend writing this using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
    SELECT m.grirno, m.grirdate
    FROM grirmain m
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM grir_pass p
                      WHERE g.grirno = p.grirno AND
                            p.ins_check IS NOT NULL AND
                            p.grirdate > DATE '2018-04-01'
                      ) AND
          m.grirno IS NOT NULL AND
          m.chkuser IS NOT NULL AND
          m.grirdate > DATE '2018-04-01'
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR (GRIRNO,INSTR (GRIRNO,'/',1,1)+ 1,(  INSTR (GRIRNO,'/',1,2)- INSTR (GRIRNO,'/',1,1)- 1))) DESC;
```

Then, you want indexes on `grir_pass(grirno, grirdate, ins_check)` and `grirmain(grirno, grirdate, chkuser)`.

Comment: Gordon -- `NOT EXISTS` is only equivalent to the OP's original query is `grir_pass.grirno` cannot be `NULL`.  And, in that case, I'm pretty sure the CBO would have converted the `NOT IN` to an antijoin anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery actually appears to be completely *non* correlated to the outer query.  As such, Oracle most likely would execute it once and cache the results to be used later.  I can suggest the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON grirmain (gridate, girano, chksuer);
```

This index should at least let Oracle handle the `WHERE` clause quickly, and in addition it covers the two columns in the `SELECT` clause.  As mentioned, the uncorrelated subquery should be executed once and then cached.

As for the `ORDER BY` clause, the index probably would not help with that, and Oracle would have to manually sort.

Comment: whether we can create idex without affecting table data

Comment: Creating an index should not affect the data in the table.  It would affect the overall database structure, since then there would be a new index, which takes up space, may affect performance in other areas, etc.